# Mock json file how do I include it in my project?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a mock json file, which I am importing in my project:

```
import data from './config/data.json';
```

How do I include it in my project so all components can use it?

I am using `react-router`

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to load old store data?

## Yes it's a store object saved previously

Then you can inject it while creating the store via preloadedState argument,
for more info head to [createStore docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/createStore.html)

```
createStore(reducer, [preloadedState], [enhancer])
```

## No it's generic data like configuration or so:

For best practice and ability to debug it later follow the Redux flow,
add action type (ex. GET_CONFIG) and dispatch it to the reducers, something like this

```js
// Create Action Type
const GET_CONFIG = 'GET_CONFIG';

// Import json (you might need to handle webpack json-loader)
import config from './config/data.json';

// Dispatch it (you can access the dispatch method from the store directly, outside the connect function)
store.dispatch({type: GET_CONFIG, config});
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your store. I'm unsure of what kind of state management you use but if you import your data.json object in your store's constructor you should be able to set some default values. On the react side of things you can then access your data.json data by accessing the store.

```
// YourStore.js
import data from './config/data.json';
class YourStore{
    constructor() {
        this.loadedData = data;
    }
}

// entry.js
import YourStore from './stores/YourStore.js';
const store = new YourStore();
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data from your json file as initialState (or as a part of it) to your [createStore](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md) function. It will then be available through your redux store throughout the app.

```
const initialState = {
   data,
   ...otherData,
}

const store = createStore(combineReducers({
    ...Reducers,
    router: routerReducer,
  }),
  initialState,
));

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main layout file like

```
<Route path="/" component={PublicLayout}>
    <IndexRoute component={LoginPage}></IndexRoute>
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}></Route>
</Route>
```

In your `PublicLayout` constructor() in

```
this.state = {
 source: data; // which is => import data from './config/data.json';
}
```

Then in your render method pass it as a prop to the child components. 
Now i don't know in which context you are using, but I think this should help.

Or an another option would be to use Redux and def`enter code here`ine a reducer and assign this json data to your redux state and then access it anywhere in the app.

Or on of the simplest way is too just use an Alias in your webpack file and make 
`import data from './config/data.json';` this as a global path which can accessed from anywhere in your code. Webpack will handle the rest.